# Latest date of specific columns in excel

Tags: excel, date

I have been a few days thinking about a problem in excel and I just can't seem to find a solution so I am trying this page for the first time.

The problem is as follows:

I have a set of columns that specify the name, type and model of different products. In addition I have a column with the date it was released and a column that says if the row is the latest in its specific name, type and model or not (they have to be the same to compare the dates).
I wanted to automate this column as I have done with others but I don't even know where to start. It seems incredibly difficult compared to the others I have done.

Sample:

- Title   **Type**     Model     **Date**         Last date?
- Fear      **Low**      B421      **06/04/15**     No
- Fear      **Low**      B421      **23/05/15**     Yes
- Hert      **Medium**   M12      **07/11/14**     No

If someone could help me with this I would really appreciate. Any clue or idea is helpful.

Comment: **Help us to help you.** Post a small sample of your data.

Comment: Did my best to post a sample.

Comment: Please have a look at my answer here: yours would be similar to the 'new business' situation where there are no earlier instances of the same product i.e. you can do it with COUNTIFS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30530423/use-an-array-formula-to-check-if-a-similar-contract-ended-in-the-last-12-months/30531914#30531914

Comment: I did a concatenation of the data and a column to say if it is unique or not, but i still can't make a column that says which one is the newest data. Sorry Tom I don't quite understand COUNTIFS very well, I used a COUNTIF for unique validation but that was the furthest I could get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK the formula you need in E2 would look like this:-

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A$2:A$4,A2,B$2:B$4,B2,C$2:C$4,C2,D$2:D$4,">"&D2),"No","Yes")
```

if the data are in columns A to D with headers in row 1. Then pull it down to E3, E4 etc.

This says:-

'If there are any matching products with a later date, then this can't be the latest one, so put "No" '.

'If there are no matching products with a later date, then this must be the latest, so put "Yes"' (or at least joint latest, if there are two or more with the same date).

[image]